# Do you need a server for SQLite

Tags: swift, sqlite

So I am creating an app for IOS with xcode and swift and I am using SQLite as a database(not my choice) and I dont understand if I need a server or not.
Thank you in advance

Comment: It depends. Does it need to be accessed remotely? Or all in "the phone" (locally)?

Comment: Well we would like to retrieve the data from all the users and convert it in CSV format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it depends on your requirement. If you want to store your data outside of the mobile itself for any reason such as fetching and updating them from multiple devices you can use a server to host your database and perform read, write operations. If not, if you only want to use your data inside your app itself, you can make use of the SQLite databases and perform read and write operations locally.

Comment: Thank you, and what kind of server would you recommend

Comment: There are plenty of ways that you can do it. You can setup SQLServer, Mongo DB or alternatively you can consume object oriented data stores such as Firebase if its convenient.

Comment: In the beginning we wanted to use Firebase but as this app is for my school they did not want a Google based service (data privacy reasons) so we went on to use SQLite( because it is me for IOS and another guy for android development). What other alternative to Firebase would you recommend?

Comment: [link](https://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/)
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No, iOS actually uses SQLite in the Core Data on the device.  Here you can see a tutorial on using SQLite in Swift on a device https://www.raywenderlich.com/6620276-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Thanks a lot !! and do you know about android studio apps ?

Comment: @AlkisLorantos Sorry, no :(

Comment: @AlkisLorantos Do you have your own website? You can use its DB to communicate with iOS and Android client apps.